# I am enabling SSO authentication for a WPF application using MSAL and Microsoft Graph API, but https://login.microsoftonline.com is not launching

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on

I am enabling SSO authentication for a WPF application using MSAL and Microsoft Graph API, I am able to get token and user information and authentication is happening, but in the browser https://login.microsoftonline.com is not getting launch.

Please find below my code sample :

```
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        private static readonly string AadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0";
        private static readonly string Tenant = "tenantid ";
        private const string ClientId = "client id";      
        private static readonly string Authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, AadInstance, Tenant);
        private IPublicClientApplication _app;

 
 // Acquire Access Token from AAD for Proxy Application
            IPublicClientApplication clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(ClientId)
            //.WithDefaultRedirectUri() // will automatically use the default Uri for native app
            .WithRedirectUri("mydesktopapp://auth")
            .WithAuthority(Authority)
            .Build();

            AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
            var accounts = await clientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
            IAccount account = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

            IEnumerable<string> scopes = new string[] { "User.Read", "openid" };

            try
            {               
                authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account).ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
            {
                authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
               
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

When acquiring the token interactively, we can use the `WithUseEmbeddedWebView(false)` as below:

```
authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithUseEmbeddedWebView(false).ExecuteAsync();
```

This worked for me.